# how can i insert image in matisse database using SQL query?

Tags: java, jdbc, matisse

i have to insert an image into the matisse database. how can i insert it through sql insert statement in java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [java.sql.PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to insert a `blob` into your database.

Example code:

```
 try{
      Connection con = getYourDatabaseConnection();
      PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE(YOUR_BLOB_COLUMN) VALUES (?)";
      statement.setObject(1, yourImage);
      statement.execute();
 } catch(SQLException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: @Makyen It's more a generic solution that should work on the most databases.

Comment: Documentation says that blob should be supported, can't test it as Matisse is a commercial software and don't provide a free version.

Comment: hi @fireandfuel how can i browse image and set it to a blob variable first?? in matisse

Comment: @Rukshan: What do you mean with "browse image"?

Comment: in your try statement "statement.setObject (1, yourImage)"....how can i get that yourImage from system and set it to blob variable?

Comment: @Rukshan It's off topic. Please search in on your own.